# Избавиться от уведомления брандмауэра Windows при запуске WCF службы

Tags: c#, tcp, wcf

У меня есть служба WCF, которая хостится в консольном приложении через net.tcp вот так:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service));
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:5005/Service"));
host.Open();
```

при запуске я получаю уведомление:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это не влияет на работу приложения, можно нажать "Отмена".

Мне нужно, чтобы это окно не появлялось. Вариант с отключением уведомлений через панель управления не подходит. Можно как-то самому ограничить функции приложения перед тем, как это принудительно сделает брендмауэр, чтобы ему нечего было ограничивать и он не выводил окно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я нашел ответ, надо вот так написать:

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service));
var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/Service"));
host.Open();
```